# Identifying Patterns in SQL DB (BigQuery)

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I am searching for a method to detect patterns in a SQL DB that contains tens of millions of legal entity names.

For example, there may be an entity name such as (a) "**XYZ** 100 Water St LLC" or (b)"**XYZ**BroadwayLLC" or (c)"**XYZ**15WallSt" or even (d)"Fee Owner **XYZ** Group"

The query would hopefully uncover that XYZ is a highly occurring series of characters and assign a value to flag these so they may be grouped for further review.

I suppose this is slightly different from Soundex or Lratio. If anyone has any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To identify frequently used words/pattern - try below approach

```
select word, count(*) frequency 
from your_table, 
unnest(regexp_extract_all(name, r'(?:\b|\d)([[:alpha:]]+)(?:\b|\d)')) word
group by word
order by frequency desc
```

if apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

After patterns extracted you can use below for "grouping"

```
with patterns as (
  select word, count(*) frequency 
  from your_table, 
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(name, r'(?:\b|\d)([[:alpha:]]+)(?:\b|\d)')) word
  group by word
)
select word, array_agg(name) names
from patterns, your_table
where regexp_contains(name, word)
group by word
having count(*) > 1
order by count(*) desc
```

with output

[image]

Obviously, you can also eliminate stop-words like St, LLC to eliminate noise

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, this was very helpful! Now I can't help but wonder whether there are tools which can detect whether a name is a 'person' or a 'thing'. For example, 'Burger King' vs 'John King'. Have any ideas on where to point me?